# jQuery - Compare string dates then add class in Repeater (C#.net webform)

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I have the following layout:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rpDB_item" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rpDB_item_ItemDataBound">
   <ItemTemplate>
      <div class="row">
          <div>...</div>
          <div>...</div>
          <div class="anj col-md-2 col-xs-2" id="bkdate" runat="server"><%# Eval("myDate") %> </div> 
          <div>...</div>
          <div>...</div>
          <div>...</div>                                                  
      </div> 
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

What I am trying to do is when `$(document).ready` check all instances of the bkdate (string) and see if it is less than today's date then `.addClass()` or `.removeClass()` depending on true/false.  I think I am just not fully understanding jQuery but could use some help.  I have the following in the `$(document).ready(Function(){...`

```
var date2 = Date.now('MM/dd/yyyy');
if ($('id*=bkdate]').val() < date2) {
        $(this).addClass("green");
  } else {
        $(this).addClass("red");
  };
```

I think the problem is with `(this)` not referencing anything.  Wha t am I doing wrong and what would be a better method?

Comment: $('id*=bkdate]').val() is going to return you a string value. So your comparison to date object is not correct. Plus, 'this' refers to the element object which invokes the event. In your js code, there is no event being triggered, so 'this' would refer to the page object

Comment: @DinoMyte, I believe the event is in `$(document).ready`.  Wouldn't `this` refer to the document?

Comment: @ScoobyDrew18: That's what meant by page.

Comment: That makes sense for this.  However for $("[id*=bkdate]").val() you can compare dates when in string value if I read things correctly, that is why I used the formatting option in now() Would something along this line work? `$("[id*=bkdate]").ready(function (e) {
                var date2 = Date.now.toString('MM/dd/yyyy').toString;
                if (e.target.val() < date2) {
                    $(this).addClass("red");
                } else {
                    $(this).addClass("green");
                }
            });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found my issue.  I changed to the data result to a DateTime.  It was implicitly converting to a string and causing the whole error.
Here is the code inside the _ItemDataBound event:

```
    ...
    HtmlGenericControl dtbackup = ((HtmlGenericControl)e.Item.FindControl("bkdate"));
DateTime date2 = DateTime.Today;
            DateTime idate = (DateTime)(DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "myDate"));
if (idate < date2)
            {
                dtbackup.Attributes.Add("class", "bad");
            }
            else
            {
                dtbackup.Attributes.Add("class", "good");
            }
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in code behind, use the itemDatabound Event, then you can do what you want there:

```
 void R1_ItemDataBound(Object Sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e) {

      // This event is raised for the header, the footer, separators, and items.

      // Execute the following logic for Items and Alternating Items.
      if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem) {

         if (((Evaluation)e.Item.DataItem).Rating == "Good") {
            ((Label)e.Item.FindControl("RatingLabel")).Text= "<b>***Good***</b>";
         }
      }
   }
```

Here you can find more information:https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.itemdatabound%28v=vs.110%29.aspx, e is the item being processed.

and for setting a css class from codebehind :

```
 if(Object<DateTime.now)
 Object.Attributes.Add("class", "some-class")
else
 Object.Attributes.Add("class", "some-class")
```

Comment: I tried something like list and am getting either a comparison error or nothing `protected void rpDB_item_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        HtmlGenericControl mdate = ((HtmlGenericControl)e.Item.FindControl("bkdate"));
  if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
        {
     string idate = (string)(DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "myDate"));
           string date2 = DateTime.Now
            if (idate < date2)
            {
                mdate.Attributes.Add("class", "myclass");
            }     }
    }`

Comment: It appears to be replacing my other classes on the container.  I have three other classes on that specific <div> and when the code renders it is only the one class I added?  Why would that be?